# Access scope on specific fuinction in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a following ambiguity in AngularJS. 
I'm using AngularJS ui Modal and provide 
controller about this modal. From this controller
I want to access variable from other scope. What is 
a angular way to do this? Here is my code:

```
   controllers.controller('ResultCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$q', 'Matches', '$modal',
        function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $q, Matches, $modal) {

            /**
             * other code
             * 
             * from this scope i can access 
             * $scope.terms
             */
            $scope.mergeTerms = function() {
                var ModalInstanceCtrl =  function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    /**
                     * Here I want to access 
                     * $scope.terms as a above 
                     * function
                     */
                }
            }

        });
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure, that your `ModalInstanceCtrl` controller will always be inside your `ResultCtrl` you could use `$scope.$parent.terms`, however this might not always be the case.

when using Angular-ui modal, you can pass objects which can be injected into your modal controller:

```
    $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        terms: function() {
          return $scope.terms;
        }
      }
    });
```

By doing this, you can simply inject terms into controller:

```
    var ModalInstanceCtrl =  function ($scope, $modalInstance, terms) {
        $scope.terms = terms;
        /**
         * Here I can access $scope.terms in terms
         * which was injected into this controller
         */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass it into the Modal Instance Controller so that it can resolve it within it's own scope. Something like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    resolve: {
        terms: function () {
            return $scope.terms;
        }
    }
});
```